# How do you disable the phone's microphone when a bluetooth headset is connected?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I would like to be able to disable the phone's microphone while a bluetooth headset is connected. The phone's microphone is disabled during phone calls but not when using voice command apps (Cyberon Voice). I've tried looking through lots of settings but to no avail. I'm on android 4.0.3 with a Samsung Galaxy S2.
I want to do this so that I can use the headset while on my motorbike.